# Change the used implementation of interface Java

Tags: java, interface

Sorry for the beginner question, my google-fu failed me.

I have an interface, let's call it Foo.
And there are two classes both implementing Foo(Bar1, Bar2).

The code does something like

```
private Foo foovar;
```

and goes on to use foovar normally.
foovar is an instance of class Bar1.

Can someone please explain why does this happen and how can I change it to be an instance of Bar2?

Thank you.

Comment: Where do you set the instance? Look for `foovar =` in the code

Comment: When you first initialise the variable Foo foovar=new Bar1(), it is at that point a Bar1, that is where you would change it to a Bar2

Comment: Are you using Spring to populate foovar? Or CDI?

Comment: Why does what happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, an interface specifies the basic set of mandatory features that a particular class implementing it must have. Suppose you have an interface "Animal"

```
public interface Animal
{
 public void eat();
 public void sleep();
}

public class Dog implements Animal
{
 public void eat()
 {
  // do something..
 }
public void sleep()
{
 // do something..
}

}
```

So somewhere else you can do,

```
Animal a = new Dog();
```

Works fine.. Because every Dog is an animal and it is BOUND BY CONTRACT TO SLEEP AND EAT (atleast..).

Comment: And just because a dog and cat both implement the Animal interface you still can't cast from dog to cat because that would be madness

Answer (score 3):

You can check if it is an instance using `instanceof`, if it is an instance you can convert is by casting it `Bar1 b = (Bar1)Foo`.

A Bar1 on the other hand is not a Bar2 - you cannot directly convert one into the other unless they provide (or you write) methods to do so. For example you might have a constructor for Bar2 that takes a Bar1.

Beyond that the behavior you are describing is a fundamental part of how inheritance works. Read up on inheritance and come back if you have a more specific question.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Factory Design pattern to get object of concrete class by passing an information such as type. Check the below example

```
 interface vehicle
{ 
    void start();
    void stop();
} 
class car implements vehicle
   {
public void start()
{
    System.out.println("Start car");
}
public void stop()
{
    System.out.println("Stop car");
}
}
class bike implements vehicle
{
public void start()
{
    System.out.println("Start bike");
}
public void stop()
{
    System.out.println("Stop bike");
}
}
class factory
 {
    public static vehicle getVehicle(int ch)
        //(?)sould be interface type
        {
            vehicle v=null;//local always inialize otherwise error
            //car c=new car();
            //bike b=new bike();
            if(ch==1)

                v=new car();


            else
                v=new bike();
                return v;


        }
 }
 class factorymain
  {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    vehicle v;
    v=factory.getVehicle(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
    v.start();
    v.stop();

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `foovar = new Bar1()` then obliviously foovar will be of instance Bar1. If you want the foovar variable to hold instance of Bar2 you have to assign new bar2 instance to it.

Answer (score 0):

foovar is a reference variable which can refer to the instances of both Bar1 and Nar2 classes.